# Node emitter : how to properly design event listeners

Tags: node.js, scope, this, eventemitter

I'm learning node:

Looking inside the EventEmitter, by default it executes callbacks by passing the emitter as *this* to the event listener, such that within your event listener function, *this* refers to the EventEmitter object.

I'm somewhat confused by this sentiment, how can an object register itself as a listener and keep a reference to its own properties?

Consider this problemo:

```
Meeting.prototype.recordStatement = function(name, statement) {
    this.minutes.push(name + " said " + statement);
};
```

It's pretty standard to use a pattern like this to create instance methods for custom objects, but this won't fly as a listener for an EventEmitter:  If I attach the recordStatement instance method of a meeting to, say, statements events emitted by, say, a person/emitter, I lose access to the meeting instance properties within the scope of the recordStatement listener, so with respect to the above example, on statement event from the person, this.minutes is undefined.

I suppose I can use an intermediate object here, which would hold a reference to the meeting instance, but, seems like a lot of wiring.

How should I design for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the function call in a closure:

```
var self = this;
emitter.on('statement', function(name, statement) {
  self.recordStatement(name, statement);
});
```

Or use `.bind()` (can be slower than using a closure):

```
emitter.on('statement', this.recordStatement.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. In other ECMAScript implementations, passing null as the first argument to apply, as in `myFunciton.apply(null, [1, 2])`, leaves the function bound to its parent. I didn't know that doing so in JavaScript will pass the global object.